# How to solve ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I can't figure out why RSpec put error.
The error message is bellows.

```
  1) ArticlesController POST #update with valid params assigns the article as @article
     Failure/Error: @article = Article.find(params[:article][:id])

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Article with 'id'=
     # ./app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:205:in `update'
     # ./spec/controllers/articles_controller_spec.rb:121:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I prepared database for RSpec test. And schema was formed and data was empty.

Here's my Article Controller

```
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:article][:id])
    @article.publish_at = params[:article][:publish_at]
    @article.publish_until = params[:article][:publish_until]
    @article.update_user_id = params[:article][:update_user_id]

    @article.article_histories.build
    @article.article_histories.last.article_id = params[:article][:id]
    @article.article_histories.last.title = params[:article_histories][:title]
    @article.article_histories.last.content = params[:article_histories][:content]
    @article.article_histories.last.version = @article.article_histories.maximum(:version) + 1
    @article.current_version = @article.article_histories.last.version

    @article.status =  Article.statuses[:ready] unless @article.scrape?
    @article.thumbnail = article_params[:file]
```

My RSpec test is like this.

```
  describe 'POST #update' do
    context 'with valid params' do
      let(:new_attributes) {
        {
          current_version: 2,
          publish_version: 2,
          thumbnail: "uploads/article/thumb/thumb_20170327055055.png",
          status: "publish",
          publish_datetime: "2017-04-16 19:51:03",
          user_id: 2,
          update_user_id: 3,
          article_histories_attributes:[
            version: 2,
            title: "Hello! again",
            content: "World!World!!! <br />"
          ]
        }
      }

      it 'assigns the article as @article' do
        article = Article.create! valid_attributes
        put :update, params: {id: article.to_param, article: new_attributes}, session: valid_session
        expect(assigns(:article)).to eq(article)
      end
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

[Update]
I modified some parameters like this. But still doesn't work.

```
RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  login_admin

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      id: 1,
      current_version: 1,
      publish_version: 1,
      thumbnail: "uploads/article/thumb/thumb_20170327055055.png",
      status: "publish",
      publish_datetime: "2017-04-16 19:51:03",
      user_id: 1,
      update_user_id: 1,
      article_histories_attributes:[
        version: 1,
        title: "Hello!",
        content: "World!World!!!"
      ]
    }
  }

  describe 'POST #update' do
    context 'with valid params' do
      let(:new_attributes) {
      {
      id: 1,
      current_version: 2,
      publish_version: 2,
      thumbnail: "uploads/article/thumb/thumb_20170327055055.png",
      status: "publish",
      publish_datetime: "2017-04-16 19:51:03",
      user_id: 2,
      update_user_id: 3,
      article_histories_attributes:[
        version: 2,
        title: "Hello! again",
        content: "World!World!!! <br />"
      ]
      }
      }
```

Comment: You are passing to the controller { id: article.to_param, article: new_attributes} . The controller expects the value passed to article to be a hash that contains an :id key , however the variable new_attributes does not contain a :id key. So You have to add it to that variable by sending { article: new_attributes.merge(article.to_param) }.    This would work

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I finally resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line is giving you an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception is this one

```
@article = Article.find(params[:article][:id])
```

You have no key `id` in the hash within `article`.

Comment: Thanks. I appended id. But error is still same. Check my questionnaire, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your try to find with params[:article][:id] but it's not in your hash. In your test you send the id that you can access it via params[:id]. If you have custom routes in your controller you should do something like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    before_action set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :custom_route]
    # your actions goes here
    # ...

    protected
    def set_article
        @article ||= Article.find(params[:id] || params[:article][:id])
    end 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified along with your advise though, still same. I have updated my description for your review.